# In an iPhone xcode app, is it possible to declare a pointer with global scope?

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers

I want to do:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass *obj = new MyClass();
```

I tried it in main.mm, inside main(), in my appDelegate.mm and inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. But none of those seem to work.

Otherwise I have to pass the pointer into every object. This involves another interface, more method calls and more #includes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

Just remember to use `extern` keyword in the translation units you are going to use the global variable.

For example, in you **main.m** file:

```
NSString* yourGlobalStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Global!"];
```

And where you are going to use it, in **other_file.m** put:

```
extern NSString* yourGlobalStr;

- (void) m
{
    NSLog(yourGlobalStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in your app delegate and then access it from anywhere like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(appDelegate.myString);
```